# Unity 5.3.4 - FileNotFoundException when deploying game to my Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, filenotfoundexception

I am getting this exception in my console each time I deploy my game to my Android device.

```
FileNotFoundException: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/PlaybackEngines/androidplayer/AndroidManifest.xml does not exist
System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:107)
System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:86)
ChartboostSDK.CBManifest.GenerateManifest () (at Assets/Chartboost/Editor/CBManifestEditor.cs:28)
ChartboostSDK.CBManifest.CheckAndFixManifest () (at Assets/Chartboost/Editor/CBManifestEditor.cs:38)
ChartboostSDK.ChartboostPostProcess.PostProcessBuild_Android (System.String path) (at Assets/Chartboost/Editor/CBPostProcess.cs:48)
ChartboostSDK.ChartboostPostProcess.OnPostProcessBuild (BuildTarget target, System.String path) (at Assets/Chartboost/Editor/CBPostProcess.cs:36)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Despite the exception, Unity is still able to build and deploy to my device successfully.

I like to point out, based on the log, that I'm using Chartboost in my project with their latest SDK (6.4.5 as of this post). I'm also using Unity 5.3.4 on Mac OS El Capitan.

Now when I playtest my game on my Android device, everything seems to be normal and working as it should: game itself, my UI, chartboost ads are working. No unexpected behaviors or anything.

Should I be worried about this? What is causing this exception and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's complaining about one of the editor scripts.  These scripts use conditional compilation to include different code snippets depending on the platform the game is running on.  Editor scripts, as you may have guessed, run in the Unity Editor.

So long story short, if it's working fine in the editor and there are no problems on your target device, you should be okay.  I could contact Chartboost though or look in to their support forums to find the root of the problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm not too worried about the editor side. This is actually quite strange as I'm getting this exception just now and I didn't modify anything in my project. I'll go ahead and contact Chartboost support to get their insight on this too. I'll post back once I get a reply.